# MySQL Query sets values to 0 with 'AND' clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that is meant to update two columns by increments of 1, or create them if they do not exist.

My current table has four columns: `id`, `username`, `playtime`, and `deathtime`.

As it stands now, this is the query I use:

```
INSERT INTO `playTime` (`username`, `playtime`, `deathtime`)
VALUES ('Rogue', 1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `playtime`=`playtime`+1
    AND `deathtime`=`deathtime`+1
```

(The username is dynamic in application, but one is provided for the example).

My issue, however, is that on a duplicate key it doesn't increment the values, rather it sets both values to 0. Through numerous tests of tweaking the query, I have found that it is the AND clause that causes the query to "reset" the values. For instance, this query will increment the playtime column correctly:

```
INSERT INTO `playTime` (`username`, `playtime`, `deathtime`)
VALUES ('Rogue', 1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `playtime`=`playtime`+1
```

And if you swap "playtime" with "deathtime", then it increments the other column correctly. Why is this?

Comment: AND is a BOOLEAN operator, for example: `1 AND 1 = 1` or `1 AND 0 = 0`. You need a comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a comma to delimit statements here.

```
INSERT INTO `playTime` (`username`, `playtime`, `deathtime`)
VALUES ('Rogue', 1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `playtime`=`playtime`+1, `deathtime`=`deathtime`+1
```

The example can be seen in the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks! Gotta love the little mistakes

Answer (score 4):

Try this..  a comma, instead of AND

```
INSERT INTO `playTime` (`username`, `playtime`, `deathtime`)
VALUES ('Rogue', 1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `playtime`=`playtime`+1 ,
     `deathtime`=`deathtime`+1
```